# How to customize Trix Editor in RoR 6

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, stimulusjs, trix

So I wanted tu customize Trix editor. For now I Have H2, H3 button (suprisingly they works) and "RED" button (change text color to red). In Trix editor almost everything is ok, but as soon as i save post, red color disapear. Same thing for ul and ol list. No dots or numbers (again in Trix editer they are visible).

**Inspect elements in view**

```
<h2>heading2</h2>
<h3>heading3</h3>
<span>red color</span>
<ul>
  <li>First position</li>
  <li>Second position</li>
</ul>
```

**Inspect element in Trix editor**

```
<h2>heading2</h2>
<h3>heading3</h3>
<span style="color: red;">red color</span>
<ul>
  <li>First position</li>
  <li>Second position</li>
</ul>
```

**trix_toolbar_post_controller.js**

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {

    connect() {

        // Grab a reference to the toolbar(s) on the page.
        const toolbar = this.element.previousSibling
        // HTML for our buttons
        const h2ButtonHTML = '<button type="button" class="trix-button" data-trix-attribute="heading" title="Subheading">H2</button>'
        const h3ButtonHTML = '<button type="button" class="trix-button" data-trix-attribute="subHeading" title="Subheading">H3</button>'
        // Only apply event listeners once to the toolbars
        const once = {
            once: true
        }

        addEventListener("trix-initialize", function(event) {
            const sibling1 = toolbar.querySelector(".trix-button--icon-increase-nesting-level")
            sibling1.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", h2ButtonHTML)
            const sibling2 = toolbar.querySelector("[data-trix-attribute='heading']")
            sibling2.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", h3ButtonHTML)
        }, once)
    }
}
```

**trix_customization.js**

```
Trix.config.blockAttributes.heading = {
  tagName: "h2",
  terminal: true,
  breakOnReturn: true,
  group: false
}

Trix.config.blockAttributes.subHeading = {
  tagName: "h3",
  terminal: true,
  breakOnReturn: true,
  group: false
}

Trix.config.textAttributes.red = {
  style: { color: "red" },
  parser: function(element) {
      return element.style.color === "red"
  },
  inheritable: true
}
```

**actiontext.scss**

```
@import "trix/dist/trix";
.trix-content {
  .attachment-gallery {
    > action-text-attachment,
    > .attachment {
      flex: 1 0 33%;
      padding: 0 0.5em;
      max-width: 33%;
    }

    &.attachment-gallery--2,
    &.attachment-gallery--4 {
      > action-text-attachment,
      > .attachment {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
      }
    }
  }

  action-text-attachment {
    .attachment {
      padding: 0 !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}

.trix ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}

.trix ol {
  list-style-type: decimal;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
}
```

**post form**

```
.p-5#post
  =form_for post, url: path do |form|
    =form.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
    .flex.flex-col.justify-center.items-center.text-center
      .flex.flex-col.mt-2
        = form.label :title
        = form.text_field :title, required: true
      .flex.flex-col.mt-2
        = form.label :meta_title
        = form.text_field :meta_title, required: true
      .flex.flex-col.mt-2
        = form.label :meta_desc
        = form.text_field :meta_desc, required: true
      .flex.flex-col.mt-2
        = form.label :slug
        = form.text_field :slug, required: true
      .flex.flex-col.my-2
        = form.label :inner
        = form.select :inner, options_for_select([[t('views.admin_dashboard.users.participants.had_training.yup'), true], [t('views.admin_dashboard.users.participants.had_training.nope'), false]]), required: true
      .flex.flex-col
        = form.label :post_date
        = form.datetime_field :post_date, required: true
      .flex.flex-col.my-2
        = form.label :image
        = form.file_field :image
      .flex.flex-col
        = form.label :status
        = form.select :status, Post.statuses.keys.map {|key| [t("activerecord.models.attributes.post.status.#{key}"), key]}, required: true
      .flex.flex-col.my-2
        = form.label :body, required: true
        = form.rich_text_area :body, data: { controller: 'trix-toolbar-post' }, class: 'w-full trix'
      =form.submit t('views.editor_portal.save_post_button'), class: 'py-2 px-4 rounded-lg border-2 border-primary-500 bg-white mt-4'
```

Ps. I'm using Tailwind.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here is solution:
**application.rb**

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes.add 'style'       
end
```

**actiontext.scss**

```
/* Tailwind Override */
.trix-content {
    width: 100%;
}

.trix-content h1 {
    font-size: 1.25rem !important;
    line-height: 1.25rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.trix-content h2 {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    line-height: 1rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.trix-content h3 {
    font-size: 0.75rem !important;
    line-height: 0.75rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.trix-content a:not(.no-underline) {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #3B82F6;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.trix-content a:visited {
    color: green;
}

.trix-content ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.trix-content ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.trix-content pre {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    white-space: pre;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.trix-content blockquote {
    border: 0 solid #ccc;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    padding-left: 0.6em;
}

.trix-editor {
    width: 100%;
}

.trix-editor h1 {
    font-size: 1.25rem !important;
    line-height: 1.25rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.trix-editor h2 {
    font-size: 1rem !important;
    line-height: 1rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.trix-editor h3 {
    font-size: 0.75rem !important;
    line-height: 0.75rem !important;
    margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.trix-editor a:not(.no-underline) {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #3B82F6;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.trix-editor a:visited {
    color: green;
}

.trix-editor ul {
    list-style-type: disc;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.trix-editor ol {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}

.trix-editor pre {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    white-space: pre;
    background-color: #eee;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.trix-editor blockquote {
    border: 0 solid #ccc;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 0.3em;
    padding-left: 0.6em;
}
```